# Query on rtsp streaming in IE using vlc plugin

Tags: javascript, stream, h.264, vlc

I am trying to do rtsp streaming in internet explorer but my code is running on localhost but not on boa server.

Following is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function play()
     {
           alert("Entered function");
           vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
           var options = new Array(":aspect-ratio=16:10","--rtsp-tcp"); 
           var urlVideofile = "rtsp://192.168.1.224:8556/PSIA/Streaming/channels/2?videoCodecType=H.264";
           var targetURL="rtsp://192.168.1.224:8556/PSIA/Streaming/channels/2?videoCodecType=H.264";
           var itemId=vlc.playlist.add(targetURL,"",options);
           var id = vlc.playlist.add(urlVideofile, null, options);
           vlc.playlist.playItem(id);
    }
</script>
<body>
    <object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" id="vlc" width="517" height="388" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">
                <param name="MRL" id="mrlVideo" value="" />
                <param name="volume" value="50" />
                <param name="autoplay" value="True" />
                <param name="loop" value="false" />
                <param name="fullscreen" value="false" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="toolbar" value="false" />
                <param name="windowless" value="true" />
            </object>
    <a href="#" onClick="play()" >Start</a>
</body>
```

Problem that I am facing is that there is no error still unable to stream, so can anybody help me out where can the problem be??